# Function literals vs function values

Tags: scala, function

Trying to figure out the significance of this section from Programming in Scala, 2nd edition.

> A function literal is compiled into a class that when instantiated at
>   run- time is a function value. Thus the distinction between function
>   literals and values is that function literals exist in the source
>   code, whereas function val- ues exist as objects at runtime. The
>   distinction is much like that between classes (source code) and
>   objects (runtime).

I don't really get what they're trying to say here.  That function values don't exist in the source code and function literals don't exist at runtime?

```
// literal
val addOne = (x: Int) => x + 1

// value
def add1(x: Int): Int = x + 1
```

I can pass either to another function:

```
def doThing(thing: Int => Int) = thing(5)

doThing(addOne) // 6
doThing(add1)   // 6
```

It also appears that function literals are placed into a class that inherits from `FunctionN` (where N is the arity of the function).  What distinction are they trying to make here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't really get what they're trying to say here.

Your example of a function literal and value aren't accurate. The book is not comparing *methods* to *functions*, it's creating a distinction between two different "modes" of a *function*. The hint is in the first sentence:

> *A function literal is compiled into a class that when instantiated at
>   run-time is a function value.*

When at compile time you type:

```
val addOne = (x: Int) => x + 1
```

This is what the book refers to as a "function literal" (or [Anonymous Function](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html)). The same way you have a *string literal* by typing:

```
val s = "Hello, World"
```

`addOne` to the compiler is a `Function1[Int, Int]`, meaning takes an `Int` and returns an `Int` result. The function literal syntax (`(x: Int) => x + 1`) is syntactic sugar over `FunctionN`, where `N` is determined by the [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) of the function.

At run-time, the compiler takes this "function literal" and "puts life into it" by instantiating an object of type `Function1[Int, Int]`, thus creating a *function value* which you can invoke, pass around, etc.

> What distinction are they trying to make here?

The book is basically trying to create a distinction between the compile time and runtime representation of a function, so when they say "function literal" you'll understand they're talking about the former, and when they say "function value" the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Scala code compiles into jvm bytecode which does not have functions but has classes. So your code `val addOne = (x: Int) => x + 1` is syntactic sugar for (I'm not precise here, only high concepts):

```
final class anonFun extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1 {
    final def apply(x: Int) = x + 1
}

val addOne = new anonFun();
```

Actually compiled files are much more complex, you can compile your scala file with `scalac -print` and see desugared scala code. Here is my compile output of small object:

```
object Main {
  val addOne = (x: Int) => x + 1
}
```

(scalac version 2.11.7)

```
package <empty> {
  object Main extends Object {
    private[this] val addOne: Function1 = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def addOne(): Function1 = Main.this.addOne;
    def <init>(): Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      Main.this.addOne = {
        (new <$anon: Function1>(): Function1)
      };
      ()
    }
  };
  @SerialVersionUID(value = 0) final <synthetic> class anonfun$1 extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcII$sp with Serializable {
    final def apply(x: Int): Int = anonfun$1.this.apply$mcII$sp(x);
    <specialized> def apply$mcII$sp(x: Int): Int = x.+(1);
    final <bridge> <artifact> def apply(v1: Object): Object = scala.Int.box(anonfun$1.this.apply(scala.Int.unbox(v1)));
    def <init>(): <$anon: Function1> = {
      anonfun$1.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

At the contrast look at compiling

```
object Main {
    def addOne(i: Int) = i + 1
}
```

(scalac version 2.11.7)

```
package <empty> {
  object Main extends Object {
    def addOne(i: Int): Int = i.+(1);
    def <init>(): Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

You can see that `def addOne` becomes just an instance method of an object, but `val addOne` is itself an object.

Comment: The referenced paragraph from the book isn't comparing *methods to functions*. It's comparing compile time vs runtime representation of a *function*.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about functions in that paragraph. It applies exactly the same to other kinds of literals, e.g. integers.

- The specific character sequence composed of the character with the ASCII value `0x34` followed by the character with the ASCII value `0x32` and surrounded by whitespace, parentheses, comma, semicolon, or some other kind of delimiter, is an integer literal.
- It will be compiled into an instance of the `Int` class. (Actually, that's not quite true: on the JVM implementation of Scala, it will be compiled into a JVM primitive `int`, and on the ECMAScript implementation of Scala, it will be compiled into an ECMAScript `Number`, and the compiler will generate additional code to "fake" it being an instance of the `scala.Int` class.)
- At runtime, it will be instantiated into an integer representing the value `42`.

Functions are no different here. The specific sequence of characters that make up a literal (whether that be a function literal, integer literal, string literal, character literal, symbol literal, tuple literal, boolean literal, or the literal value `null`) exist only in the source code. The values those literals represent exist only at runtime. The compile time representation of those literals is as an instance of some class.